# Why is a success message considered an error in ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

```
import ftplib
server = '192.168.1.109'
user = 'bob'
password = 'likes_sandwiches'

box = ftplib.FTP(server)
box.login(user, password)

s = box.mkd('\\a\\this4\\')
box.close()

x = raw_input('done, eat sandwiches now')
```

This returns:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scripts\ftp_test.py", line 25, in 
    s = box.mkd('\E\this4\')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ftplib.py", line 553, in mkd
    return parse257(resp)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\ftplib.py", line 651, in parse257
    raise error_reply, resp
error_reply: 250 Directory created successfully.

It successfully created a directory, but it thinks its an error! WTF?

I plan on creating many directories in a loop, how can I do this without having it break every time it successfully creates a single directory?

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 959](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html) (FTP), the only valid response code to MKD is 257. Looks like this is a problem caused by the FTP server not conforming to the standard.

For your interest, this is the relevant ftplib code:

```
if resp[:3] != '257':
    raise error_reply, resp
```

Comment: ok, looks like my FTP server talks with an accent. There's no way for me to change it. How can I form a loop to create directories and ignore all these exceptions it will throw at me then?

Comment: @ruffiko, with the voidcmd method, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Instead of ignoring exceptions, you should probably go for Alex’ answer and use voidcmd.

Answer (score 1):

`ftplib` is expecting a result of 257, defined as " created", so it can parse the `<pathname>` and return it for you; but your server is surprisingly giving a result of 250 and does **not** return the pathname, so the `mkd` method of course fails.

As a workaround to this peculiar server behavior, you can use [voidcmd](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd) to just send the `MKD /your/path` command -- after all, you *know* the pathname you want to create, since it's an absolute one.