# What is the DRYest way to extend/patch a library in ruby?

Tags: ruby, dry, quirks-mode, class-extensions

I wonder what's the best way to write a modular extension of an existing library in ruby that **alters existing methods**. It should not introduce repetition of code and should be used on demand only.

The specific task I'm trying to accomplish is extending ruby's `Net::FTP` module for support of some [not so standards compliant servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463033/why-is-a-success-message-considered-an-error-in-ftplib). Such an extension should be completely seperated from the standards compliant library IMHO.

I thought requiring an additional file would be quite nice since that would not even pose the necessity for some kind of switch in the original code. So an additional `require 'net/ftp/forgiving'` would make the original library a bit more forgiving regarding our less gifted FTP server fellows.

The relevant file can then make use of ruby's open class and module architecture to patch the FTP class. For fixing the example of quirky behavior linked above I would need to patch `Net::FTP#mkdir`. which would look like this:

```
#content of net/ftp/forgiving
require 'net/ftp'

module Net
  class FTP

    # mkdir that will accept a '250 Directory created' as a valid response
    def mkdir(dirname)
      begin
        original_mkdir(dirname)
      rescue FTPReplyError => e
        raise unless e.message.start_with? '250 Directory created'
        return ""
      end
    end

  end
end
```

However this would require to somehow cache away the original `Net::FTP#mkdir` as `Net::FTP#original_mkdir` to keep the code DRY. Is this possible? Do you have any further suggestions on how to improve this method of patching/extending? Or maybe even completely different approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "monkeypatching" and is exactly the use case that [`alias_method`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method) was made for:

```
alias_method :original_mkdir, :mkdir
def mkdir(dirname)
  begin
    original_mkdir(dirname)
  rescue FTPReplyError => e
    raise unless e.message.start_with? '250 Directory created'
    return ""
  end
end
```

Although this is an often-seen "idiom" in Ruby, this **will break existing code** (maybe even code inside `Net`) that relies on `mkdir` raising an exception in this case. You can't limit these changes to files which `require 'net/ftp/forgiving'` only. Thus, it would be much cleaner to create a subclass rather than open up the original class:

```
module Net
  class ForgivingFTP < FTP
    # mkdir that will accept a '250 Directory created' as a valid response
    def mkdir(dirname)
      begin
        super(dirname)
      rescue FTPReplyError => e
        raise unless e.message.start_with? '250 Directory created'
        return ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Or even better, place it in a custom namespace! A good rule of thumb is:

> subclass when *possible*, monkeypatch when *necessary*.

(Thanks to @tadman for this). In this case it doesn't seem to be necessary.

**UPDATE:** Following up on your comment, if you want to extend only a specific instance the `Net::FTP` class, you can extend their singleton classes:

```
obj = Net::FTP.new
class << obj
  alias_method :original_mkdir, :mkdir
  def mkdir(dirname)
    #...
    original_mkdir(dirname)
    #...
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, subclass when *possible*, monkeypatch when *necessary*.

Comment: @tadman: Couldn't have formulated it better (and haven't, in fact :) Mind that I quoted you?

Comment: I'm sure it's been said before, but sure!

Comment: Thanks for the hint on `alias_method`. I completely agree that in most cases it's not wise to change the behavior of existing methods, especially when it comes to standard libraries. However in this case I'm just patching code to behave like it was intended to under certain adverse conditions. On the other hand I see that requiring such a patch would put any `Net::FTP` object in the whole application into *quirks mode* which isn't desirable either. Could this be done in some other way that just affects certain instances? Like conditionally applying the patches on a method call (via `include`)?

Comment: @tadman: BTW, your profile text could be simplified and optimized to `%w[ Yes No Maybe ].sample` :P

Comment: @tadman What if I was the original author of that lib and just wanted to keep the *quirks mode code* separated without making it actually visible to users?

Comment: @raphinesse: If you have specific instances that you want to patch, you can extend the singleton class. I'll add example code for that.

Comment: @NiklasB: Thanks for your elaborate answer. I think I know what to do now in my specific case. However I'm still interested in the possible solutions for the scenario I mentioned above: "What if I was the original author of that lib and just wanted to keep the *quirks mode code* separated without making it actually visible to users?" I created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265920/how-to-separate-good-code-from-legacy-quirks-mode-code) for this.